# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching vbox11 found

Tags: java, ssl-certificate

I have written Junit code for functional test. Here i am consuming the REST service from the Junit framework. below is the URL:

"https://vbox11:8443/myapp/myservice?&_application=appName&_operation=updateTrail&_profile=mysql&_method=NULL&_format=JSON&user=BLR"

Strange thing is same framework was working earlier but after i reinstall the Linux machine. it is throwing below error:

main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching vbox11 found.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching vbox11 found.
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1937)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1478)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:212)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:969)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:904)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1050)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1363)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1391)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1512)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1440)Finalizer, called close()

        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)Finalizer, called closeInternal(true)
```

It would be free helpful if you guys help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are connecting over ssl (https) and the certificate in the web server is not matching the host name in the url. Specifically the certificate should have alternate host names included as extensions and one should match vbox11.

Comment: The specific entry where the url has to match is "Certificate Subject Alt Name" in the extensions.